# Rails: NoMethodError: undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Al intentar realizar una multiplicación en `rail`, me genera dicho error.
si alguien pudiera colaborarme se lo agradecería mucho

```
Failure/Error: self.sub_total_price_menu = menu.price1 * quantity
```

> NoMethodError:    undefined method *' for nil:NilClass

Comment: `menu.price1` es nulo (i.e. `nil`), verifica que se asigne correctamente un valor antes de realizar la multiplicación.

Answer (score 1):

El error es porque `menu.price1` es `nil` o **nulo** en Ruby.

En caso de que exista la posibilidad de que el primer valor puede ser nulo, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
(menu.price1 || 0) * 2
```

En caso de que el primer valor sea nulo, este toma el valor 0.

Así no te mostrará error y considerarás el caso del valor nulo.